# Difficulty saving a template while appending strings

Tags: c#, excel, file-io

I'm attempting to load an excel template and then save it with a machine name and datetime appended to the filename. The issue im running into is that the final product ends up like:

"Template.xlsx_MachineName_DateTime.xlsx"

I can't seem to find a method for getting rid of the first .xlsx. I first open a file dialog and save the path as a string.

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
                string fileName = fileDialog.FileName;
```

Then I use FileStream to save the file.

```
                using (FileStream outputfile = new FileStream(fileName + machineInfo.HostName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    package.SaveAs(outputfile);
                }
```

Has anyone encountered this before? I feel like there should be a way to use path.combine but can't come up with anything. Ideally I want the result to be "Template_MachineName_DateTime.xlsx".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the System.IO.Path class to get hold of specific parts of a filename / path.

```
 string fileName = fileDialog.FileName;
 string newFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + 
           machineInfo.HostName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx"
```

Or if you want something that would work with any file extension (not just .xlsx):

```
 string fileName = fileDialog.FileName;
 string newFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + 
         machineInfo.HostName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + 
         System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
```

The Path class has a lot of very useful methods when dealing with files and directories.

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend reading up on [MSDNs String Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

```
string filename = fileDialog.FileName;
string newFilename;
int fileExtensionIndex = filename.LastIndexOf(".xlsx")

newFilename = filename.Insert(fileExtensionIndex
                             ,"_" + machineInfo.HostName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

using (FileStream outputfile = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    package.SaveAs(outputfile);
}
```